# Какое название этой структуры данных?

Tags: алгоритм, графы, структуры-данных

При решении одной задачи возникла структура данных, являющаяся ориентированным графом, но с оговорками. Каждой вершине *v<sub>i</sub>* приписано некоторое натуральное число *n<sub>i</sub>*. Далее будет ясно, что оно означает:

Выберем некоторую вершину. Она соединена ориентированными рёбрами с некоторыми другими вершинами. Выберем любое ребро и пойдём по нему. Будем повторять эту процедуру пока не зайдём в "тупик" (далее станет более ясно, почему процесс прекратиться и что такое "тупик"). Таким образом, образовался некий путь от начальной вершины до "тупика", но со следующими правилами:

1. Через точку *v<sub>i</sub>* можно проходить не более, чем *n<sub>i</sub>* раз
2. Точка называется "тупиком", если из неё нельзя больше попасть ни в одну вершину графа. Причём это может быть по двум причинам:

   - либо из этой точки не исходит ни одного ребра
   - либо в какую-бы следующую вершину *v<sub>i</sub>* мы не направились, её соответствующее число *n<sub>i</sub>* уже исчерпалось по пути (то есть *v<sub>i</sub>* уже встретилась в пути *n<sub>i</sub>* раз) (также ясно, что из-за этого свойства, является точка тупиком или нет вообще зависит от пройденного нами пути)
3. Если есть возможность продолжить путь в какую-нибудь вершину, то ею обязательно нужно воспользоваться (то есть последней точкой любого пути всегда является "тупик")

В итоге такой путь, удовлетворяющий этим трём правилам, думаю, можно назвать тупиковым

Изначальная моя задача такая: для заданного ориентированного графа из заданной вершины построить все тупиковые пути. Эту задачу я уже решил, но мне интересно изучить эту структуру данных. И мои вопросы: как она называется? можно ли о ней где-то найти информацию для изучения?

Comment: Это похоже на релаксацию ("ослабление") в вершинах - однако для вершин такое понятие вроде не вводилось, а вот для рёбер - бывает (алг. Форда-Беллмана)

Comment: Я не уверен полностью, но мне кажется, что ваша задача частично включает в себя задачу о гамильтоновом пути и даже является ее обощением. Таким образом, много информации, просто любопытствуя, вы не найдете - даже гамильтонов путь сломать уже два века не могут, а вы тут усложняете его. Если же интерес профессиональный, то вам надо идти на math.stackexchange

Comment: Поясню, почему я вижу в вашей задачу обобщение задачи о гамильтоновом пути: если у всех вершин `n_i = 1`, то самый длинный тупиковый путь либо является гамильтоновым путем, либо показывает, что в заданном графе гамильтонова пути нет. А именно это и требуется найти.

Comment: /*пятиминутка занудства*/ когда говорят о «Структурах данных» применительно к графам, то обычно имеют в виду то, что используют для хранения оных — *списки/матрицы смежности/инцидентности* и т.п... вопрос скорее должен звучать «как называется эта задача»...

Comment: вряд ли у этой задачи есть какое-то специальное название — как уже сказали ближе всего, пожалуй, поиск всех возможных гамильтоновых путей методом полного перебора без отсечения неудачных попыток т.к. после того как каждую вершину продублировать `n_i` раз всё сводится именно к этому... также в принципе всё это близко к банальному поиску в глубину...